# How to "clone" from a running instance with Qt?

Tags: qt, clone, qt4.7

I want to make a copy of the current running application , like Chromium browser , when i click on some button.

For now i'm using:

`QProcess::startDetached( QApplication::applicationFilePath() );`

But this is not `cloning` from the running application.

*EDIT*

I tried to fork() , and got a X11 error:

```
XX: Fatal IO error: client killed
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
RenRenPhotoFetch: ../../src/xcb_io.c:273: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

Comment: Try adding a log call at the start of the application, maybe its starting and not getting very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "cloning"? If you mean a Unix-style fork() creating an identical copy of the process: There isn't a cross-platform API for this in Qt, as fork() is a Unix thing and not available on e.g. Windows. If you only target Unix, you can of course can just call fork().